# how to make a singed apk file with javafxPorts

Tags: apk, signed, javafxports, gluon

anybody here developers with javafxPorts?

I was interested in gluon project, but some of sample gluon mobile sources in eclipse plugin doesn't make a signed apk file to upload the Google play store.
if you succeed in making a signed apk file, please let me know the detail solution.

i'm sure it doesnt work.
1) install Eclipse Mars(4.5.2) + Gluon Tools (e(fx)clipse IDE 2.3.0, Gradle IDE 3.7.3..)
2) Gluon Sample project (all of them including Gluon Mobile - Single or Multi View Project)
3) it works about a debug apk file through gradle, but not a release signed apk file.

is it wrong???

`jfxmobile {`

`android {`

`manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'`

`androidSdk = 'F:/android/android-sdk'`

```
    signingConfigs {
       release {
           storeFile file("mykey.keytool"))
           storePassword "test"
           keyAlias "kdc"
           keyPassword "test"
      }
  }
```

`}`

`}`

what is that mean??

No such property: manifest for class: org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.task.AndroidTask_Decorated

[BUILD FAILED]

please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the jfxmobile plugin there is no support for multiple configurations. The `android` task (which generates a debug apk) will **always** be signed with a debug keystore. To generate a signed release apk, you directly specify the `signingConfig` configuration and use the `androidRelease` task.

```
jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        signingConfig {
            storeFile file('my.keystore')
            storePassword 'storePass'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'keyPass'
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I didn't specify a name for the signing configuration.

Comment: Oh~ Joery.  After I cut tag "release" in signingConfig, it works well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @DaeChulKang happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted, by clicking the check mark beside the answer.